# Is message-broadcastig (in a lokal network) a client/server or a peere-to-peere system?

Tags: networking, server, client

I am curious as to what type of system I have when I send broadcast-messages to all my devices in a local network. Is it a client/server system or a peer-to-peer system?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "_I send broadcast-messages to all my devices in a local network._" That is an old, deprecated way to do things. Broadcast interrupts _every_ host on a LAN, including hosts not interested (routers, printers, etc.), and it wastes bandwidth. That is why broadcasting has been eliminated from IPv6, so your application cannot be ported to IPv6. The modern way to do it is with multicast, which only interrupts the hosts interested in receiving the multicast.

Comment: In any case, the client/server concept does not apply to networks, but to the applications. The network protocols do not have clients or servers, it is the applications that provide services (servers) or consume the services (clients).